# Avoding infinite loop in Firebase with child_added/child_changed

Tags: javascript, firebase

I’m trying to create a worker process that listens to Firebase for additions/changes to a particular collection. In either case, a process should run that eventually writes some additional data back to the collection based on what it finds there. The problem I’m running into is that this causes an infinite loop because child_changed will fire the callback again because I’m changing models in the same tree it’s listening to. Also, there’s an initial duplication of work with the first pass through child_added triggering child_changed.

The only solution I’ve come up with is to somehow put data into Firebase that indicates that a no update should occur (`is_dirty: false`, or something to that effect). I’m not particularly happy with that solution because that requires the client to be involved in flipping a flag or something when it adds/changes something that should trigger processing by the server. I’d prefer they not be that coupled. I certainly do like the idea of maintaining some sort of cache collection to compare for changes, since that would duplicate a lot of data.

I also considering using `off` somehow right before the update (turning it back on afterwards) but I’m afraid that would cause me to miss changes that might come in during that window of time. Maybe this is a case for transactions?

What’s the best practice here? Currently, my code looks like this:

```
collectionRef.on('child_added', processModel);
collectionRef.on('child_changed', processModel);

var processModel = function (modelSnapshot) {
  // do some stuff that updates model
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Without knowing your use case, it's a little bit hard to answer this, but I'll provide some general thinking.]

It's important to keep in mind that Firebase synchronizes data, not "events."  And so every time you restart your worker process, it's going to get child_added events for all of the existing data.

Additionally, if your worker process has been down for an hour and users have made a bunch of changes to items in the model, when your worker process starts up again, it'll still just get a bunch of child_added events, not individual child_changed events for the changes that were made offline.

So you generally want to do one of two things:

1. Store a "worker queue" in Firebase and have your worker process grab items off the queue, process them, and then discard them (or flag them completed or move them to a different location or whatever).
2. Store a "state" in each model object, that indicates what state it's in to indicate what processing needs to happen (similar to your dirty idea).  A user might add an item as "initial" and your worker process would pick it up, do its processing, and write it back with the state of "processed" or something like that.  If a client makes modifications, it'd mark it "dirty", and again your worker process would make its modifications and update the state to "processed"

If you follow one of these approaches, it should be easy for your worker process to know which items it needs to process, and it should gracefully handle restarts / downtime, etc., correctly "picking up" where it left off.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Re: what happens when the worker starts, that was intentional. The worker is supposed to guarantee the database contains the information it provides and that it's up-to-date, so if it goes down and comes back up, I wanted it to make no assumptions and process everything to be safe. That said, I think I'll need to implement one of those plans as a better alternative, despite my initial misgivings. The queue as a particular advantage in that I can store references to relevant locations.

Comment: The other option (which I don't recommend) is to set a flag during your writes (i.e. "localUpdate = true; ref.set('some data you want to ignore.'); localUpdate = false;") and then in your event handlers, you check for localUpdate and if it's true, ignore the event.  But this relies on the fact that .set() raises events synchronously, which we may change in a future revision of the API.

Comment: Here's an example [work queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue). These are extremely useful.

Comment: I saw that one, @Kato, thanks. I ended up going with [firework](https://github.com/mjijackson/firework) though.

Answer (score 2):

Your main process and worker process are (by default) very loosely bound - only being linked by the fact one modifies data and the other is told data haz changed.

Adding a queue or semaphore is a way of binding them more tightly.

However, my preferred model would generally be to bind them even less tightly...

Instead of thinking about events, think about the state of the data.

Design your worker process to take a dirty database and make it clean. Then treat 'on update' calls as an optimisation - effectively giving your worker process a 'clue' as to which part of the database *may* need cleaning.

Using this pattern means no 'infinite update' issue as once clean, no additional updates are performed, and its very scalable - you could have several worker processes working on different parts of the database, or cleaning different elements in different ways.

The down side is that the data does have to be structured to work in 'states' and programs using the data must be designed with the possibility of the data they read being dirty. Although if this seriously matters, I would get the client reading the data to check if it is dirty and trigger a clean before proceeding...

Comment: This is closer to the approach I was hoping to take, I think. My venture into queues has raised a number of complexities that weren't even an issue before. However, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "treat 'on update' calls as an optimisation - effectively giving your worker process a 'clue' as to which part of the database may need cleaning." Would you elaborate? Are you essentially suggesting that clients save to a staging area and the worker cleans and saves to the final collection?

Comment: Without more info on your actual data its hard to be more specific. My thinking was to initially design the cleaner code to fix the whole database (as if traversing the whole DB on a schedule), then refining/optimising it be called with on update to just clean the bit it needs to based on the update. Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: Fund has many Portfolios has many Positions. The user can add new portfolios (with at least 1 position), add new positions under an existing portfolio, change the position's symbol or change the portfolio's date. Any of this will will require the worker to fetch market data from a third-party, do some calculations, and attach that results to each position so they can be displayed. It's okay for the client to not have this performance data in the meantime. The worker also updates these metrics on a schedule for existing models. Is that enough information?

Comment: @neverfox a couple of thoughts - if you have the market data in a separate record you can simply check for its existence to see if it needs adding or not. Also - an on value event will only fire if the data actually changes - so if the market data is in the main record, the event will only fire if it actually changes... This in itself could avoid the infinite loop you are worried about.

Comment: Sorry, storing the market data isn't an option. In any case, there's still the need to process that data differently based on changes to the portfolio/position attributes, even when the market data itself hasn't changed (different relevant dates or symbols etc.). It's certainly possible to perform these calculations client-side, but performance was unacceptable. So far, I have a work queue that's getting the job done. I'm just curious to understand your suggested alternative more.

Comment: I could store the fields that will be updated by the server as a detached record, I suppose, reacting to child_added/child_changed on the main record, as I was before. One of the nice things, though, about the queue approach is that I can only submit jobs when *relevant* changes occur.

Comment: Yes when I said 'market data' I meant market dependent data.